# How to read multiple text file filled with columns calculating statistics perl

Tags: perl, statistics, measurement

I'm running some network measurements where I now get a ton of timestamps according to this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNnBf.png

I want to get the statistics of Mean, Var & CoV and the problem I have is that I  don't really know how to read in the text files so I get the right values in the right array.

I saw that Bash was considered poor in this area so I decided that perl should be better. This is my attempt so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#foreach $line

$pkt_number  = $1;
$pkt_arrival = $2;
$pkt_size    = $6;

$nr_of_pkg                = 16;
$linespeed                = 100000;
$sum_of_throughput        = 0;
$throughput               = 0;
$sum_of_throughputsquared = 0;
$mean                     = 0;
$var                      = 0;
$co_v                     = 0;

$duration = $pkt_arrival[0] - $pkt_arrival[15];

for (my $i = 0 ; $nr_of_pkg > $pkt_number[i] ; $i++) {
  $throughput[i]             = $packet_size[i] / $pkt_arrival[i];
  $sum_of_throughput         = $sum_of_throughput + $throughput[i];
  $sum_of_throughput_squared = $sum_of_throughput_squared + $throughput[i] * $throughput[i];
}

$mean = $sum_of_throughput / $nr_of_pkg;
$var  = (($sum_of_throughput * $sum_of_throughput) - $sum_of_throughput_squared);
$co_v = sqrt($var)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to achieve this, I have spent quite some time on it and this is what I got so far. I.E. I need some guidance.

Comment: It is tiresome to have to tidy up your Perl code before I can understand it. Please try to present your code properly, especially if you are asking for help with it. You should also reserve capital letters for global identifiers, such as package names. Lexical identifiers should contain only lower-case letters, decimal digits and underscores

Comment: Sorry, thanks for tidying it up.
I'm sitting over ssh and copied it from there but I totally agree and I will take all of that in mind!

Comment: Without any idea what your data or the code that surrounds this sample look like, and what output you're hoping for, we don't stand a chance of helping you. What you have already looks fine

Comment: I have tried to reformulate and added a picture etc.

Comment: Could you copy-paste 1 or 2 lines of text from the input file?

Comment: It's in the imgur.com link(wasn't allowed to add the picture to show instantly)  sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to read and parse the text file.

```
my @pkt_number;
my @pkt_arrival;
my @pkt_size;

my $i = 0;
my $line;
while ( <> ) { 
    $line = " $_"; # make sure it always start with a whitespace
    chomp $line;
    ( $pkt_number[$i], $pkt_arrival[$i], $pkt_size[$i] )
        = (split( /\s+/, $line, 8 ))[ 1, 2, 6 ];
    printf "[%s]\n", join("/", $pkt_number[$i], $pkt_arrival[$i], $pkt_size[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

And this is how you run it on Linux :

```
% cat result.txt | ./your_perl.pl
```

Comment: Thanks @tivn this was what I was what I was asking for, haven't tested it yet but seems legit!